# Ansible Python Interpreter shows different version

Tags: python, ansible

I am trying to use an ansible playbook via vagrant. I want it to use python 3x so I set:
`ansible_python_interpreter: "/usr/bin/python3"`
But, it shows me an error saying:
`Ansible requires a minimum of Python2 version 2.6 or Python3 version 3.5. Current version: 3.4.3`
When I check ansible version using `ansible --version`, it shows python version to be 3.8.5

And if I try to explicitly mention python version:
`ansible_python_interpreter: "/usr/bin/python3.8"`
or
`ansible_python_interpreter: "/usr/local/lib/python3.8"`
It throws a not found error even though these python installations do exist.

What could be causing this anomaly and how can I fix this?

Comment: What does `head -1 $(which ansible)` return? Perhaps your `ansible` is using a different Python installation?

Comment: It return this ```#!/usr/bin/env python3```

Comment: Ok then it finds the interpreter based on `PATH`. Can you check what `which python3` returns? Also, do you have the same Python version installed on all your target machines?

Comment: which python3 returns ```/usr/bin/python3```. There are not any target machines yet, I am just testing a script.

Comment: This is prompted to you because the nodes you are running your playbook on do not have the right python version. Mind that Ansible ships python scripts from your controller to your nodes  and then your nodes do execute those python scripts, so you need the right python version *on the nodes* too.

Comment: How do I upgrade their python versions remotely?

Comment: With Ansible, of course ;) Using the [`package` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/package_module.html) should comes in handy.